# How do I determine how many spells a character learns per level?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-advancement

I'm a new DM and I have a relatively simple question that I can't seem to find a good answer to: How do I determine how many spells a character gets to learn upon leveling up?

For example: The table for a wizard shows that a level one wizard knows 3 cantrips and gets 2 level one spell slots. Does this also mean they know 2 level one spells? Now, suppose they level up to level 2. They get an extra level one spell slot, so do they get an extra level one spell? At level 3, it gets more confusing, because they now get an extra level one spell slot and 2 new level 2 slots. How many spells does the wizard now know?

More generally, is there a way to figure out how many spells a character is able to learn per level which applies to all classes? Does it depend on class?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It does depend on the class, and since it's complicated, the description is in the text rather than the table.

1. Wizards don't really *know* spells (except for cantrips) — they add them to their
   spellbooks, which can happen while adventuring in addition to those
   they learn on level-headed. This is under "[Learning Spells of 1st
   level or
   higher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/wizard#LearningSpellsof1stLevelandHigher)"
   in the book.
2. Most "divine" casters — clerics, paladins, druids — don't learn individual 
   spells 
   . They know *all* of them (but prepare a limited subset
   per day).
3. Other casters — sorcerers, rangers, warlocks, bards — do have a
   fixed number of Spells Known, and in this case, you *will* find it
   on the class table. See for example [the
   sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#TheSorcererTable)
   or
   [ranger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#CreatingaRanger).
4. This is also true for the martial and roguish archetypes which add
   spellcasting — each of these have a special second table. For
   example, [Eldritch
   Knight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight)
   (link will work if you own the PHB on D&D Beyond; otherwise, check
   your paper copy).

(This isn't a duplicate, but answers turn out to be similar because the same thing needs to be explained: [What happens when I can prepare more spells than I have slots to cast them with?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110168/what-happens-when-i-can-prepare-more-spells-than-i-have-slots-to-cast-them-with/110177#110177))