# Why does the Starter Set wizard have six spells in their spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, character-creation, wizard, pregenerated-characters

[One of the characters in the Starter Set is a 1st-level high elf wizard with an Int mod of +3.](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Charactersv2.pdf#page=7) How does this character have 6 spells?

I understand that one is a ritual, but it has 5 more and not 4?

The spellbook shows:

1. *burning hands*
2. *detect magic* (ritual)
3. *mage armor*
4. *magic missile*
5. *shield*
6. *sleep*

I had the same original question myself. This is a premade character sheet licensed by D&D.

Comment: Is [this](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/rpg_starterset) the starter set you're referring to?

Comment: See also this on [known spells, prepared spells, and spell slots](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110168/what-happens-when-i-can-prepare-more-spells-than-i-have-slots-to-cast-them-with/110177#110177) — I suspect this is some of your confusion.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 50):

While this might not be the case in the Starter Set you are looking at, in the official rules (the full *Player's Handbook*), [1st-level wizards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Spellbook) (PHB 114) are granted a spellbook containing 6 spells. They can then prepare a number of spells equal to *their wizard level + Int modifier* for casting (in this case, 4) using their two 1st-level spell slots.

#### Spellcasting/Spellbook

> At 1st level, you have a spellbook containing **six 1st-level wizard
> spells** of your choice.

#### Spellcasting/Preparing and Casting Spells

> You prepare the list of wizard spells that are available for you to
> cast. To do so, choose a number of wizard spells from your spellbook
> equal to **your Intelligence modifier + your wizard level** (minimum
> of one spell).

Without viewing the source you are referring to, it seems that the 6 spells listed are their initial 6 spells in their spellbook, from which the player must prepare 4 spells each day to actually have available to cast. *Detect magic*, being a ritual spell, can still be prepared and cast as a standard action using one of the two spell slots, or it can cast as a ritual, in which case it does not need to be prepared and takes 10 additional minutes to cast.

In short, as far as I can determine, the character sheet is correct.

Comment: The Starter Set uses the same rules.

Answer (score 8):

This is quite straightforwardly explained in the [character sheet](https://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Charactersv2.pdf#page=7):

> **Spell Slots**. You have two 1st-level spell slots you can use to cast your prepared spells.
>
> **Prepared Spells.** You prepare four 1st-level spells to make them available for you to cast, **choosing from the spells in your spellbook**.
>
> **Spellbook**. You have a spellbook containing these 1st-level spells: *burning hands*, *detect magic*, *mage armor*, *magic missile*, *shield*, and *sleep*.

The default starting wizard has a spellbook with those six 1st-level spells. You can only prepare four of those. You only have enough spell slots to cast two before a long rest. (The Arcane Recovery ability listed on the character sheet also allows the 1st-level wizard to recover one slot, once per day, on a short rest.)

The rules for spellcasting are given on page 21 of the Starter Set rulebook.